# How do I store and retrieve a selected date object from datetimepicker to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is code that that sends and receives the data from firebase respectively.

```
class Fire {
    addAppointment(currentDate, addComplete) {
            firebase.firestore()
                .collection("appointment")
                .add({
                    date: currentDate.date,
                    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                }).then((snapshot) => snapshot.get())
                .then((dateInfo) => addComplete(dateInfo.data()))
                .catch((error) => alert(error));
        }

        getAppointment = async ({ dateRetreived }) => {
            var dateList = [];

            var snapshot = await firebase.firestore()
                .collection("appointment")
                .orderBy('createdAt')
                .get()

            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const dateCreated = doc.data();
                dateCreated.id = doc.id;
                dateList.push(dateCreated);
            });

            dateRetreived(dateList);
        }
}

Fire.shared = new Fire();
export default Fire;
```

This is the datetimepicker code that sends the "currentDate" to the code above. Note that onChange has been changed to handleChange.

```
class Booking extends Component {
    state = {
        isDatePickerVisible: false,
        date: new Date(),

    };

    showDateTimePicker = () => {
        this.setState({
            isDatePickerVisible: true
        })
    }

    hideDateTimePicker = () => {
        this.setState({
            isDatePickerVisible: false
        })
    }

    handleChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
        const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            currentDate: prevState.currentDate = currentDate
          }));
      };


    render() {
        return (
            <View>

                <View style={styles.picker}>
                    <Button
                        title="Show Date Picker" onPress={this.showDateTimePicker}
                    />
                    <DateTimePicker
                        cancelTextIOS={'Exit'}
                        confirmTextIOS={'OK'}
                        isVisible={this.state.isDatePickerVisible}
                        mode="date"
                        onConfirm={this.handleChange}
                        onCancel={this.hideDateTimePicker} 
                        is24Hour={false} 
                    />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.btn} >
                    <Button
                        onPress={() =>
                            Fire.shared.addAppointment(this.handleChange)
                        }
                        title="Book"
                    />
                </View>
            </View>

        )
    };
};

export default Booking;
```

I get an error saying:

> FirebaseError: function documentReference.set() called with invalid data. unsupported field value: undefined (found in field date)

I made a few changes to the code:

```
addAppointment(currentDate, addComplete) {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("appointment")
            .add({
                date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(currentDate)),
             ...
    }
```

AND
On state:

```
   state = {
            isDatePickerVisible: false,
            Date: new Date(1598051730000),

        };
```

On handling change

```
  handleChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
            const currentDate = selectedDate || Date;
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                currentDate: prevState.currentDate = currentDate
              }));
          };
```

On DateTimePicker

```
onConfirm={this.handleChange}
```

On Book button

```
<Button onPress={() => {Fire.shared.addAppointment(this.handleChange)}}
                        title="Book"
                    />
```

I don't get a  `ReferenceError: date is not defined` after selecting the date. When i press BOOK, no error happens and no data shows in Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I struggled so much, that I brought the addAppointment method into the DatePicker.js file. This is what worked for me.

```
const Booking = () => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const showMode = currentMode => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
    };

    const showDatepicker = () => {
        showMode('date');
    };

    const showTimepicker = () => {
        showMode('time');
    };

    const onChange = (event, date) => {
        const currentDate = date;
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        setDate(currentDate);
        console.warn(currentDate);
    };

    const addAppointment = () => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("appointment")
            .add({
                uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
                date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date),
                createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            }).then((snapshot) => snapshot.get())
            .catch((error) => alert(error));
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <View>

                <View style={styles.picker}>
                    <Button onPress={showDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.picker}>
                    <Button onPress={showTimepicker} title="Show time picker!" />
                </View>
                {show && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                        testID="dateTimePicker"
                        timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
                        value={date}
                        mode={mode}
                        is24Hour={true}
                        display="default"
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                )}
            </View>

            <View style={styles.btn} >
                <Button
                    onPress={() => addAppointment(onChange)}
                    title="Book"
                />
            </View>
        </View >

    );
};

export default Booking;
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer

Comment: @yogesh, honestly I don't know why date worked and currentDate didn't. I have started learning JavaScript from the beginning, so maybe I'll understand how it worked as I learn.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing your `Date` in your state, there's no need to pass it as argument. Just access it directly:

```js
<Button onPress={() => {Fire.shared.addAppointment(this.onChange)}} title="Book" />
```

```js
addAppointment(addComplete) {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("appointment")
    .add({
      date: this.state.currentDate.date,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })
    .then((snapshot) => snapshot.get())
    .then((dateInfo) => addComplete(dateInfo.data()))
    .catch((error) => alert(error));
}
```

Comment: I changed onChange back to handleChange because I was getting this; Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
ReferenceError: date is not defined
ReferenceError: date is not defined
    at Object.Booking._this.onChange [as onConfirm] 
    at DateTimePickerModal._this.handleChange

Comment: I did not pass the argument in the addAppointment function, and I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentDate' of undefined`

Comment: I get a ReferenceError.  `ReferenceError: currentDate is not defined`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentDate' of undefined
reportException @ C:\Users\…ptionsManager.js:44
handleException @ C:\Users\…tionsManager.js:113
handleError @ C:\Users\…ErrorHandling.js:23`

Comment: I got it to work with uploading the selected date now I'm having difficulties displaying the data in the Flatlist after reteival. I can see the array in the console

Comment: I put the addAppointment method in the DatePicker.js file and set `date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date)`. On the button i typed `onPress={() => addAppointment(onChange)}`

Comment: I changed DatePicker to the example provided by @react-native-community/datetimepicker, (Github)